# Infer Swift initialiser from a primitive value

Tags: swift

I have the following Swift enum that ensures only pure json types are used.

```
public enum JSONValue {
    case string(String)
    case integer(Int)
    case double(Double)
    case bool(Bool)

    public init(_ value: String) {
        self = .string(value)
    }

    public init(_ value: Int) {
        self = .integer(value)
    }

    public init(_ value: Double) {
        self = .double(value)
    }

    public init(_ value: Bool) {
        self = .bool(value)
    }
}
```

To initialise a JSON value, one has to do

```
let json = JSONValue.string("my value")
```

or in a case of a dictionary

```
let params: [String: JSONValue] = [
    "my string": JSONValue.string("my value"),
    "my int": JSONValue.init(10)
]
```

Isn't there a way to infer the initialiser from the primitive value to facilitate the usage like this:

```
let json: JSONValue = "my value"

let params: [String: JSONValue] = [
    "my string": "my value",
    "my int": 10
]
```

(off topic but if you wonder why I need this JSONValue enum, [this is the reason](https://medium.com/grand-parade/parsing-fields-in-codable-structs-that-can-be-of-any-json-type-e0283d5edb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to conform to the following protocols:

- `ExpressibleByBooleanLiteral`
- `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`
- `ExpressibleByFloatLiteral`
- `ExpressibleByStringLiteral`

Like this

```
public enum JSONValue: ExpressibleByBooleanLiteral, ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral, ExpressibleByFloatLiteral, ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
    public typealias BooleanLiteralType = Bool
    public typealias IntegerLiteralType = Int
    public typealias FloatLiteralType = Double
    public typealias StringLiteralType = String

    case string(String)
    case integer(Int)
    case double(Double)
    case bool(Bool)

    public init(stringLiteral value: String) {
        self = .string(value)
    }

    public init(integerLiteral value: Int) {
        self = .integer(value)
    }

    public init(floatLiteral value: Double) {
        self = .double(value)
    }

    public init(booleanLiteral value: Bool) {
        self = .bool(value)
    }
}
```

This will allow the compiler to perform some magic:

```
let jsonValue: JSONValue = "Hello World"
```

Comment: That's the way to go. Though while your example works fine, creating a `JSONValue` from a non-litteral does not work: `let json: JSONValue = UUID().uuidString`  yields "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to specified type 'JSONValue'"

Comment: @Jan As far as I am concerned, this is the best you can do with implicit type conversions. Swift is designed to hide as little information from the reader as possible. You have to make every type conversion very clear.